# Any way to programatically get key of google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I understand how to get sheet key of a google spreadsheet using script, is there a way to get the key to the script file associated with the sheet through script? For example:

https://script.google.com/macros/d/I_Want_This_String/edit

Comment: if you explained whay you wanted that we could provide alternatives

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to do that.